# I can't get enum class operators to work

Tags: c++, c++11

I get an error as

> `FastOut<NMAX>::Flags FastOut<NMAX>::operator&(FastOut<NMAX>::Flags, FastOut<NMAX>::Flags)` must take either zero or one argument

```
template<int NMAX>
class FastOut{
enum class Flags;
protected:
    char buffer[NMAX];
    std::map<Flags,bool>FM={(UP,0),(LOW,0),(BOOL,0)};
public:
    enum class Flags{upper,lower,boolapha };
    friend  Flags operator&(Flags a,Flags b);
    FastOut();
    FastOut(const char *);
    FastOut(const std::string&);
    FastOut & operator << (int);
    FastOut & operator << (char);
    FastOut & operator << (long long);
    FastOut & operator << (float);
    FastOut & operator << (double);
    FastOut & operator << (char *);
    FastOut & operator << (const std::string &);
    FastOut & operator << (const FastOut&);
    void open(const char*);
    void open(const std::string&);
    void flush();
    void clear();
    ~FastOut();
};
template<int NMAX>
typename FastOut<NMAX>::Flags FastOut<NMAX>::operator&(Flags a,Flags b){

}
```

I want to be able to say `FasOut<N>::Flags a= FastOut<N>::Flags::upper |  FastOut<N>::Flags::lower`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of incoherent bits of code. And **copy-paste** an example that you've verified fails with the error you're describing. Your post is littered with typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary operator *member* should only take one parameter, the right-hand argument – the left-hand argument is `*this`.

```
template<int NMAX>
typename FastOut<NMAX>::Flags FastOut<NMAX>::operator&(Flags rhs) const
{
    // Return *this & rhs
}
```